# Meeting Calendar | How to take care of the overlapping meetings to show in the calendar?

Tags: javascript, html, css, calendar

Sorry for the long question.

I have tried to create a meetings on a calendar for a day. I need help to take care of the overlapping intervals.

The code I have written in following :

**HTML**

```
<body>
  <div id="timeline"></div>
  <div id="calendar" class="calendar">
  </div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
.calendar {
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  width: 600px;
  height: 1440px;
  left: 60px;
}

.event {
  position: absolute;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 0px solid red;
}

#timeline {
  position: absolute;
  float: left;
}
```

**JS**

```
function getRandomColor() {
  var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
  var color = '#';
  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
  }
  return color;
}

function creatTimeline(tl) {
  var i = 0;
  while (i < tl.length) {
    var divEl = document.createElement('div');
    divEl.style.width = '50px';
    divEl.style.height = '120px';
    divEl.style.border = '0px solid yellow';
    divEl.innerHTML = tl[i];
    var timeLine = document.getElementById('timeline');
    timeLine.appendChild(divEl);
    i++;
  }
}

function appendEventDivs(eventArr) {
  var i = 0;
  while (i < eventArr.length) {
    var eventEl = document.createElement('div');
    eventEl.className = 'event';
    eventEl.style.height = eventArr[i].height;
    eventEl.style.top = eventArr[i].top;
    eventEl.style.background = eventArr[i].color;
    eventEl.style.width = eventArr[i].width;
    eventEl.style.left = eventArr[i].left;
    eventEl.innerHTML = 'Meeting' + eventArr[i].id;
    var cl = document.getElementById('calendar');
    cl.appendChild(eventEl);
    i++;
  }
}

function collidesWith(a, b) {
  return a.end > b.start && a.start < b.end;
}

function checkCollision(eventArr) {
  for (var i = 0; i < eventArr.length; i++) {
    eventArr[i].cols = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < eventArr.length; j++) {
      if (collidesWith(eventArr[i], eventArr[j])) {
        eventArr[i].cols.push(i);
      }
    }
  }

  return eventArr;
}

function updateEvents(eventArr) {
  eventArr = checkCollision(eventArr);
  var arr = [];
  arr = eventArr.map(function(el) {
      //just to differentiate each event with different colours
    el.color = getRandomColor();

    el.height = (el.end - el.start) * 2 + 'px';
    el.top = (el.start) * 2 + 'px';
    el.width = (600 / el.cols.length) + 'px';
    return el;
  });
  return arr;
}

var events = [{
  id: 123,
  start: 60,
  end: 150
}, {
  id: 124,
  start: 540,
  end: 570
}, {
  id: 125,
  start: 555,
  end: 600
}, {
  id: 126,
  start: 585,
  end: 660
}];

var timeline = ['9AM', '10AM', '11AM', '12Noon', '1PM', '2PM', '3PM', '4PM', '5PM', '6PM', '7PM', '8PM', '9PM'];

function getEvents (eventArr) {
  eventArr.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.start - b.start;
  });
  eventArr = updateEvents(eventArr);
  appendEventDivs(eventArr);
    console.log(eventArr);
  //PART 1 - function returning the eventArr with all the required attributes
  return eventArr;
};

creatTimeline(timeline);
getEvents(events);
```

Working fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/VaibhavP17/ftbjan06/)

Can anybody guide me how to take care of the overlapping intervals so that they appear side-by-side and not on top of each other.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to figure out in which column each of the events should be before you can determine their width or left-position. To do this, you need to also store which of the colliding events came before each event:

```
function checkCollision(eventArr) {
  for (var i = 0; i < eventArr.length; i++) {
    eventArr[i].cols = [];
    eventArr[i].colsBefore=[];
    for (var j = 0; j < eventArr.length; j++) {
      if (collidesWith(eventArr[i], eventArr[j])) {
        eventArr[i].cols.push(j);
        if(i>j) eventArr[i].colsBefore.push(j); //also list which of the conflicts came before
      }
    }
  }
  return eventArr;
}
```

Now, we can figure out the column of each event. Once we've done that, we can figure out how wide they should be, and with that, the horizontal positioning should be easy. This should be done inside your `updateEvents` function. I've got more detailed explanation commented in the comments of the code below.

```
function updateEvents(eventArr) {
  eventArr = checkCollision(eventArr);
  var arr=eventArr.slice(0); //clone the array
  for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
    var el=arr[i];
    el.color = getRandomColor();
    el.height = (el.end - el.start) * 2 + 'px';
    el.top = (el.start) * 2 + 'px';

    if(i>0 && el.colsBefore.length>0){ //check column if not the first event and the event has collisions with prior events
      if(arr[i-1].column>0){ //if previous event wasn't in the first column, there may be space to the left of it
        for(var j=0;j<arr[i-1].column;j++){ //look through all the columns to the left of the previous event
          if(el.colsBefore.indexOf(i-(j+2))===-1){ //the current event doesn't collide with the event being checked...
            el.column=arr[i-(j+2)].column; //...and can be put in the same column as it
          }
        }
        if(typeof el.column==='undefined') el.column=arr[i-1].column+1; //if there wasn't any free space, but it ito the right of the previous event
      }else{
        var column=0;
        for(var j=0;j<el.colsBefore.length;j++){ //go through each column to see where's space...
          if(arr[el.colsBefore[el.colsBefore.length-1-j]].column==column) column++;
        }
        el.column=column;
      }
    }else el.column=0;
  }
  //We need the column for every event before we can determine the appropriate width and left-position, so this is in a different for-loop:
  for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
    arr[i].totalColumns=0;
    if(arr[i].cols.length>1){ //if event collides
      var conflictGroup=[]; //store here each column in the current event group
      var conflictingColumns=[]; //and here the column of each of the events in the group
      addConflictsToGroup(arr[i]);
      function addConflictsToGroup(a){
        for(k=0;k<a.cols.length;k++){
          if(conflictGroup.indexOf(a.cols[k])===-1){ //don't add same event twice to avoid infinite loop
            conflictGroup.push(a.cols[k]);
            conflictingColumns.push(arr[a.cols[k]].column);
            addConflictsToGroup(arr[a.cols[k]]); //check also the events this event conflicts with
          }
        }
      }
      arr[i].totalColumns=Math.max.apply(null, conflictingColumns); //set the greatest value as number of columns
    }
    arr[i].width=(600/(arr[i].totalColumns+1))+'px';
    arr[i].left=(600/(arr[i].totalColumns+1)*arr[i].column)+'px';
  }
  return arr;
}
```

Working Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ilpo/ftbjan06/5/
I added a few other events to test different scenarios.

Oh, and by the way, `absolutely positioned elements` can't `float`.

Comment: You are awesome Sir !!!! Thanks a lot :)
I will keep in mind not to float the absolutely positioned elements :)

Comment: I am still trying to figure out how you actually came up with this solution... :\

Comment: Oh was my explanation unclear or does it need elaboration? Honestly, was so ready to give up after working for two hours on it in fiddle and half an hour without saving, and then creating an infinite loop and having the tab crash & lost my work... so at that point I might've started slacking off a little with the comments lol. I'll look into improving my commentary maybe tomorrow if I have time.

Comment: Yes I can see a lot of work has gone into this one. It is a piece of great art, an average coder like me would take little time to understand it. You are a rockstar ....!!! (I wish I could give you a SO tag right away..!!!).

Answer (score 0):

You already know the top and height of every event, so you could map the calendar and check an event already exist within the area it will occupy, then offset the left value by the number of existing events.

Comment: How exactly am I going to make a map with the number of columns and providing the offset ? Can you please elaborate it a bit ? A small code would be just awesome :)