# Arranging overlapping elements side-by-side for daily schedule view

Tags: javascript, html, css, user-interface, flexbox

I'm having a scenario where **I'd like to list activities in a vertical timeline, and if any activities overlap time-wise (positioned from the top of the parent div), they should share the width of the space** (think of any basic calenday day-view really).

For example:
[image]

In my mind it seems like it should be quite doable, at least partly, using flex CSS (perhaps with some addition of JS). But I'm having trouble formulating a feasible solution. Am I barking up the wrong tree here and and a script based solution is the only way to achieve this?

I found [this old post and functional answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37302106/meeting-calendar-how-to-take-care-of-the-overlapping-meetings-to-show-in-the-c), but perhaps now eight years later, there is a better way to approach this? And if there's a better UI-solution all together I'd be open to alternate solutions as well.